# Change position of unsubscribe link in Exacttarget

Tags: marketing-cloud

I want to move the unsubscribe link from automatically being placed at the bottom of the email to the top of the email. How do I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to assume you are using Email Templates, because if you were using HTML paste it would be as simple as moving the link in the email contents HTML.

In ExactTarget, each [Delivery Profile](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/send_classifications/) has an associated Header and Footer content block. You have 3 options: None, Account Default, or Library Content. By default, the Account Default header & footer has the unsubscribe link in the footer. The Account Defaults are only editable by ET support, while the Library Content option uses Content Areas to pull in the header and footer.

So in short you have two options:

1. Call ET support and have them make the change to the Account Default header & footer for you.
2. Create new Content Areas for the header and footer, and update your Delivery Profile(s) to use Library content instead of the Account Default.